# Beamer successive overlay actions in reverse order

Tags: beamer, overlays, loops

I try to make this macro work in reverse order, I mean the display is made from the left in a stared version instead from the right, ex :

`...=8` , `...=2*2*2=8` , `2^2=2*2*2=8`

I can't imagine how to do that (if it's possible) with overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\BeamerRep}{%
D<>{\ldots} % transition
m           % premier
O{}         % intermédiaires
m           % dernier
}{%
\onslide<.->{#2=}%
\foreach \q in {#3} {%
    \only<.-.>{#1}%
    \onslide<+->{\q=}%
}%
\only<.-.>{#1}%
\onslide<+->{#4}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item $\BeamerRep{3\times5+20}[15+20]{35}$
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which part is bothering you?

Comment: The [...] in the middle, all arguments in one {...} would be better, dont't you think? I try to make it reversely : `...=8` , `...=2*2*2=8` ,  `2^2=2*2*2=8`. But I have problems with overlays.

Answer (score 2):

This is a halfway construction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\addpause#1{\rotatebox{180}{$\mathord{}=#1$}\pause}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\BeamerRep{>{\SplitList{=}}m}{
    \edef\tempA{{\tl_reverse_items:n{#1}}}
    \expandafter\ProcessList\tempA{\addpause}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\Huge
    \rotatebox{180}{\BeamerRep{aA=bB=cC}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a goog idea to rotate the box us side down twice. I'll try with this.

Comment: @Tarass It is not my idea. Such workaround seems to exist in [other fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25695025).